# Arduino UCS2 to UTF text form

Tags: c++, utf-8, arduino, ucs2

I have output from my device in UCS2.
This UCS2 is in hex, and I make from ucs2 hex utf8 hex., these hexes are in String form. The question is, how to make from this hexes normal text form?
I tried to do something, one guy sent me a code piece to convert `String` to  `byte`, but still, I have a problem. I find out, that when you use `byte f = {0x56};` and then print it into the serial, it will write `"V"`, but the problem is, the utf8 hex in byte is just `"56"` ... and I don't know how to get there `"0x"`... Thanks for any help :)

My code:

```
byte charToVal(char c)
{
  switch (c)
  {
  case 'a'...'f':
    return (byte)(c - 'a' + 10);
  case 'A'...'F':
    return (byte)(c - 'A' + 10);
  case '0'...'9':
    return (byte)(c - '0');
  }
}

String toUTF8(String ucs2in)
{
  String utf8;
  for(int i; i < (ucs2in.length()/4);i++)
  {
      String endstr[4],startstr[4], ucs2[4];
      boolean ok = false;
      ucs2[0] = ucs2in.substring(i*4,i*4+1);
      ucs2[1] = ucs2in.substring(i*4+1,i*4+2);
      ucs2[2] = ucs2in.substring(i*4+2,i*4+3);
      ucs2[3] = ucs2in.substring(i*4+3,i*4+4);      

      if(ucs2[1] == "4") endstr[0] = "d";
      else endstr[0] = "c";
      endstr[3] = ucs2[3];

      if(ucs2 == NULL) break;
      if(ucs2[2].toInt() < 8) if(ucs2[2].toInt() > 0 || ucs2[2] == "0")  ok=true;

      if(ucs2[1] == "0" && ok)
      {
          endstr[0]="";
          endstr[1]="";
          endstr[2] = ucs2[2];
          endstr[3] = ucs2[3];
      }      
      else
      {
          if(ucs2[2] == "0" || ucs2[2] == "1" || ucs2[2] == "2" || ucs2[2] == "3")
          {
              if(ucs2[2] == "0") endstr[2] = "8";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "1") endstr[2] = "9";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "2") endstr[2] = "a";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "3") endstr[2] = "b";

              if(ucs2[1] == "1") endstr[1] = "4";
              else if(ucs2[1] == "2") endstr[1] = "8";
              else if(ucs2[1] == "3") endstr[1] = "c";
          }
          else if(ucs2[2] == "4" || ucs2[2] == "5" || ucs2[2] == "6" || ucs2[2] == "7")
          {
              if(ucs2[2] == "4") endstr[2] = "8";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "5") endstr[2] = "9";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "6") endstr[2] = "a";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "7") endstr[2] = "b";

              if(ucs2[1] == "1") endstr[1] = "5";
              else if(ucs2[1] == "2") endstr[1] = "9";
              else if(ucs2[1] == "3") endstr[1] = "d";
          }
          else if(ucs2[2] == "8" || ucs2[2] == "9" || ucs2[2] == "a" || ucs2[2] == "b")
          {
              if(ucs2[2] == "8") endstr[2] = "8";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "9") endstr[2] = "9";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "a") endstr[2] = "a";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "b") endstr[2] = "b";

              else if(ucs2[1] == "1") endstr[1] = "6";
              else if(ucs2[1] == "2") endstr[1] = "a";
              else if(ucs2[1] == "3") endstr[1] = "e";
          }
          else if(ucs2[2] == "C" || ucs2[2] == "D" || ucs2[2] == "E" || ucs2[2] == "F")
          {
              if(ucs2[2] == "C") endstr[2] = "8";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "D") endstr[2] = "9";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "E") endstr[2] = "a";
              else if(ucs2[2] == "F") endstr[2] = "b";

              if(ucs2[1] == "0") endstr[1] = "3";
              else if(ucs2[1] == "1") endstr[1] = "7";
              else if(ucs2[1] == "2") endstr[1] = "b";
              else if(ucs2[1] == "3") endstr[1] = "f";
          }
      }
      String finalstr = endstr[0] + endstr[1] + endstr[2] + endstr[3];
      char finalchar, val, hex[10];
      finalstr.toCharArray(hex,10);      

      boolean onlyone=false;
      if(finalstr.length()  <= 2) onlyone = true;
      if(!onlyone)
      {
          finalchar = (charToVal(hex[0]) << 4) + charToVal(hex[1]); 
          utf8 += String(finalchar);
      }
      finalchar = (charToVal(hex[2]) << 4) + charToVal(hex[3]); 
      utf8 += String(finalchar);
  }
  return utf8;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(toUTF8("005600E1017e0065006e00Fd0020007a00E1006b0061007a006e00Ed006b002c00200063006800630065006d00650020005600E1006d0020006f007a006e00E1006d00690165002c0020017e0065002000560061016100610020007a00E1007300690065006c006b00610020006a006500200070007200690070007200610076006e00E10020006e0061002000760079007a0064007600690068006e0075007400690065002000210020007700770077002e0061006c007a0061002e0073006b"));
}

void loop() 
{

}
```

Output is ⸮áž⸮⸮ý⸮⸮á⸮⸮⸮⸮í⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮á⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮á⸮⸮ť⸮⸮ž⸮⸮⸮⸮š⸮⸮⸮á⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮á⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮

and i want Vážený zákazník, chceme Vám oznámiť ....
I can't solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the input string?

Comment: Look void setup :)

Comment: any ideas guys ?

Comment: Does arduino compiler have `c++11` standard library `<codecvt>` functions?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that ... there was problem with ..

```
      if(finalstr.length()  == 4) onlyone = true;
  if(onlyone)
  {
      finalchar = (charToVal(hex[0]) << 4) + charToVal(hex[1]); 
      utf8 += String(finalchar);

      finalchar = (charToVal(hex[2]) << 4) + charToVal(hex[3]); 
      utf8 += String(finalchar);
  }
  else
  {
    finalchar = (charToVal(hex[0]) << 4) + charToVal(hex[1]); 
    utf8 += String(finalchar);
  }
```